# Регулярка для замены тега code на pre code

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В примере тег code заменён src.

есть задача найти все теги < src > ... < /src >

и заключить в < pre> < src class=''> ... < /src >< /pre>

у тега src может быть атрибут lang

регулярка

```
$sText = preg_replace("/<src * lang=(.*?)>(.*)<\/src\>/is", "<pre><src class=$1>$2</src></pre>", $sText);
```

Работает при одном блоке < src > ... < /src >

делает 
< pre>< src class=''>..< /src>< /pre>

при нескольких делает так

```
< pre >
< src src class='' > ... < /src > 
< src src class=''> ... < /src > 
< /pre>
```

А нужно так

```
< pre >
< src src class='' > ... < /src > 
< /pre>
< pre >
< src src class=''> ... < /src > 
< /pre>
```

Сам решить задачу не смог. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно считерить и сделать:

```
$sText = str_replace("<src", "<pre><src", $sText);
$sText = str_replace("</src>", "</src></pre>", $sText);
```

Comment: Отписал на аскдеве, но данный пример скорее всего будет быстрее